# Building XNU For A4 iPhone/iPod

Tags: iphone, arm, xnu

im trying to use winocm's xnu kernel "http://goo.gl/GuJnWn"  ive partially used this http://goo.gl/TK6iUZ guide to get ctfconvert, ctfmerge and ctfdump. I think i have everything i need but i get this error after typing make in the folder i was in

```
1 error generated.
make[6]: *** [gdt.o] Error 1
make[6]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
AS machine_routines_asm.o
CC machine_task.o
CC machine_check.o
CC machine_routines.o
CC locks_i386.o
CC mp_desc.o
CC pcb.o
make[5]: *** [build_all] Error 2
make[4]: *** [do_all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [build_all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [build_all_conf] Error 2
make[1]: *** [build_all_osfmk] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

/Users/gili/Desktop/xnu-master/BUILD/obj//EXPORT_HDRS/osfmk/mach/vm_region.h:284:2: error: 
  unknown type name 'vm32_size_t'; did you mean 'vm_size_t'?
    vm32_size_t     size;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
    vm_size_t
```

Comment: You are not including the actual error message, only the summary.

Answer (score 0):

clang is telling you what to do. You need to either correct the vm32_size_t to a vm_size_t by editing the file, or supply it as a macro (#define - i.e. -dvm32_size_t=vm_size_t) to go on. This is a minor issue, and the compilation should work for you.